# Meteor publishing field issue

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish

My application is publishing a 'memberPrice' field when it is not supposed to. In my publish.js file, I specified the memberPrice to not be published. Here is my server/publish.js:

```
Meteor.publish('cars', function() {
return Products.find({category: 'vehicle'}, {limit: 10}, {fields: {memberPrice: 0}});
});
```

My controller:

```
carsController = RouteController.extend({
waitOn: function () { 

    var sessionId = Session.get('sessionId');
    console.log("Session: ", sessionId);
    Meteor.subscribe('cars');
    Meteor.subscribe('cartItems', sessionId);

},
action: function() {
    this.render('Cars');
}

});
```

Here's my table using the aldeed:tabular package:

```
TabularTables = {};

Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

TabularTables.Cars = new Tabular.Table({
name: "Cars",
collection: Products,
columns: [
{data: "productCode", title: "Product Code"},
{data: "brand", title: "Brand"},
{data: "productLineName", title: "Product Name"},
{data: "description", title: "Description"},
{data: "memberPrice", title: "Member Price"}

 ]
});
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: the `cartItems publish` what is returning? another collection? or `Products collection` cursor too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past i do publish like the one you have, but since i read this post from [David Weldon](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) page.

I change my publish to something like this.

```
Meteor.publish('cars', function() {
  var selector = {category: 'vehicle'};
  var options = {limit: 10,fields: {memberPrice: false}};
  return Products.find(selector,options);
});
```

Based on the Publish function you have, the memberPrice option should be exclude here, try with this, here we are following the correct syntaxis of the Collection.find wich is `collection.find([selector], [options])` and you have something like `collection.find([selector],[selector],[options])`.

Comment: Haha, it's "Weldon" actually. Also maybe you should add a small precision of what was important on that article.

Comment: @Kyll haha i think im going to delete this, since i don't see the Peep answer wich is the same, im just changing the publish syntaxis here.

Comment: Damn I have no idea how you got that accepted, Peppe L-G's answer makes way more sense! Edit - oh wait, now I've read your edit. Good call there.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing three arguments to `Products.find`, but it only expects two. `{limit: 10}, {fields: {memberPrice: 0}}` should be `{limit: 10, fields: {memberPrice: 0}}`.